# JSF2 unsubscribe a global system event listener programmatically

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is there a way to unsubscribe a global system event listener programmatically in JSF2 that is added by a third party (jsf 2 ) related jar through its own faces-config.xml?

I understand there are 2 methods in `javax.faces.application.Application` (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/faces/application/Application.html) to unsubscribe and one of them is `unsubscribeFromEvent(java.lang.Class<? extends SystemEvent> systemEventClass, java.lang.Class<?> sourceClass, SystemEventListener listener)`.

The first two arguments of the above method are fine but how do we get hold of the listener object that was earlier registered.

Why i need to unsubscribe is so as to provide a custom behaviour for the listener. Also can this be accomplished via another global system event listener for the system event of type PostConstructApplicationEvent (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PostConstructApplicationEvent.html)?

Need: We make use of both Prime Faces (PF) and Omni Faces (OF) a lot in our web based projects. Within PF we have customized DataTable and DataTableRenderer a bit to do complex mixing of static and dynamic columns with in the header and tbody section. Recently i was porting to PF ver 4 and it all worked fine but recently PF snapshot added a new system event listener named DynamicColumnsListener and the behaviour of this listener is causing issues for us. That's why i need to unsubscribe this listener and provide my own custom listener for the extension i have implemented.

Update: Implementation of PrimeFaces event listener DynamicColumnsListener's processEvent method is

```
    Columns columns = (Columns) event.getSource();        
    ((DataTable) columns.getParent()).setDynamicColumns(columns);
```

As per the PrimeFaces implementation of DataTable and DataTableRenderer this is all fine but in my extension i can have dynamic columns in the "header" facet too and then its parent is org.primefaces.component.row.Row instead of DataTable so it runs into ClassCastException as its parent in the header facet is not DataTable but Row.

Comment: It's perhaps a better idea to tell why exactly you need this, then we could make it configurable from OmniFaces side on.

Comment: Just updated the question as BalusC suggested

Comment: Oh right, the problem is in PrimeFaces side, not in OmniFaces side. I'll remove the OmniFaces tag.

Comment: Yep its on the PrimeFaces side, but is not really an issue from their perspective, but yes it's a problem for my extension so looking for a generic way of unsubscribing a global system event listener.

Comment: As far as I see, this is unfortunately not possible. You might want to reframe your question in such way that you just tell about the issues you're encountering with PrimeFaces event listener and ask how to solve that.

Comment: Just updated the actual issue due to PrimeFaces DynamicColumnsListener as advised by BalusC

Comment: Nasty problem :) I'm not seeing a solution without hacking around with PrimeFaces classes yourself or at least try to report an issue to PF guys and tell that they should be doing an instanceof check beforehand.

Comment: Yes if they do at least an instanceof check it will suffice for me..will report on PrimeFaces too. But thanks BalusC for at least looking into this.

Comment: Added an issue on PrimeFaces, issue # 5481 at https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5841

Comment: PrimeFaces team just fixed this issue. https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5841

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case you could just override the Columns component.

```
package com.company;

public class Columns extends org.primefaces.component.columns.Columns {
}
```

And in faces-config.xml:

```
<component>
    <component-type>org.primefaces.component.Columns</component-type>
    <component-class>com.company.Columns</component-class>
</component>
```

Since DynamicColumnsListener is attached to `org.primefaces.component.columns.Columns` specifically, it wouldn't apply to the overriden component.

Or perhaps you could get the listener instance with reflection tricks, e.g. by calling Mojarra's `com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl#getListeners`.